# Send data like a table from excel into Amazon chime group using webhooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel and I am trying to write a VBA code where if the cell C5 is 'True' then I need to send a message with combination of first line has the message in E1 cell and the next line should have data like a table from E2 to H3 into a Amazon Chime group using webhook link. The message should go as:

Alert: There is variance found
The table as shown in the image. I tried to write a code, but it does not help could anyone suggest. Attached the image.

```
Sub SendDataToChimeWebhook()
    Dim chimeUrl As String
    Dim messageToSend As String
    Dim tableData As Range
    Dim tableToSend As String
    Dim httpReq As Object
    
    chimeUrl = "https://hooks.chime.aws/incomingwebhooks/your-webhook-url"
    
    If Range("C5").Value = "True" Then
        
        messageToSend = Range("E1").Value
        
        Set tableData = Range("E2:H3")
        
        tableToSend = "<table border=""1"">"
        For Each Row In tableData.Rows
            tableToSend = tableToSend & "<tr>"
            For Each cell In Row.Cells
                tableToSend = tableToSend & "<td>" & cell.Value & "</td>"
            Next cell
            tableToSend = tableToSend & "</tr>"
        Next Row
        tableToSend = tableToSend & "</table>"
        
        messageToSend = messageToSend & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & tableToSend
        
        Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
        httpReq.Open "POST", chimeUrl, False
        httpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        httpReq.send ("{""content"": """ & messageToSend & """}")
        
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]